# Adding vbNewLine into my CSV file for text formatting

Tags: vb.net, csv, formatting

I am using VB.NET to create a simple quiz program that reads questions and possible answers from two CSV files and displays them to the user.

Question CSV file:

```
Question ID, Question Text, Correct Answer
1, "Which of these are green? A: Grass B: The Ocean C: A Strawberry D: A tree leaf", A
```

Answer CSV file with four possible answers which match the questions by ID

```
Question ID, Answer A, Answer B, Answer C, Answer D
1, "A & D", "A & C, "D & B, "B & C"
```

I read my CSV file using a text field parser and store each question's 'Question' text as a string. So the question Text for question ID 1 will be `"Which of these are green? A: Grass, B: The Ocean, C: A Strawberry, D: A tree leaf"`.

I then display this question text on my GUI using a label text property. My issue is, because the string is all on one line, it formats as:

"Which of these are green? Grass The Ocean A Strawberry A tree leaf".

Id like it to format as:

Which of these are green?

A: Grass

B: The Ocean

C: A Strawberry

D: A tree leaf

Now obviously just adding vbNewLine at the desired points within the CSV file will just add "vbNewLine" as part of the string, rather than read it as code.

Is there any other solution whereby i can add something into my CSV to have my desired formatting?

Answer (score 0):

A CSV file can contain line breaks and other special characters in a field value if that value is wrapped in quotes, which yours is.  Simply add the line breaks to your CSV file and the `TextFieldParser` will read them as you expect.  E.g.

1, "Which of these are green?

A: Grass

B: The Ocean

C: A Strawberry

D: A tree leaf", A

```
Using reader As New TextFieldParser(Path.Combine(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments,
                                                 "Test.txt")) With {.Delimiters = {","},
                                                                    .HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = True}
    Dim fields = reader.ReadFields()

    For Each field As String In fields
        MessageBox.Show(field)
    Next
End Using
```

Comment: Could you show me an example of how i would change my CSV file to add in the line breaks? I have added vbNewLine before each of 'A:' 'B:' 'C:' 'D:' but it displays as

"Which of these are green? vbNewLine A: Grass vbNewLine B: The Ocean vbNewLine C: A Strawberry vbNewLine D: A tree leaf"

Comment: Open your eyes.

Comment: Perhaps with a little less passive aggressiveness would be more helpful.

Comment: I wasn't being passive. I've shown you what to do. Do it.  If you're asking, without actually asking, how to write code to generate a CSV file containing line breaks then you need to use your head too. Does your file not already have multiple records in it, on separate lines? If it does then you already know how to add line breaks to a text file.  If you really have no idea then I suggest that you open Google in your browser and type some thing like "add line breaks to text file vb.net". I've already answered the question you asked.